# Modulus of continuity of the Dirichlet Laplacian problem

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I remember the following statement is correct but I cannot find a reference for that, can anybody help me to give one?

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open, bounded, smooth domain,
$\varphi\in C\left(\partial\Omega\right).$ Let $u$ be the unique
solution of the Dirichlet problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
\triangle u & =0\quad\textrm{in }\Omega,\\
u & =\varphi\quad\textrm{on }\partial\Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
Then there exists $C>0$ s.t 
$$
\omega_{u}\leq C\omega_{\varphi},
$$
where $\omega_{f}$ denotes the modulus of continuity of $f;$ $\omega_{f}\left(\delta\right):=\sup\left\{ \left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|:\left|x-y\right|<\delta\right\} .$

Comment: When bounding $|u(y)-u(x)|$ you can reduce to the case $x\in\partial\Omega$ by the maximum principle, and then $y\in\partial\Omega$ too, via a supersolution (here should appear C).

Comment: Can u give some more hints. The right hand side is proportional to $\omega_{\varphi}$, not just depending on $\omega_{\varphi}$.

Comment: Sadly, after searching online, I 've learned that this is not correct even $\Omega $ is a ball.

Comment: In fact, following my hints above you just get a mod of cont. $\omega'$ for the solution, but it is not dominated by $\omega$...

Comment: So a modified question could be: what moduli of continuity for $\phi$ admit solutions with the same m.of (times a constant).

Comment: I think we shoud  ask: what are properties of the domain in which the modulus of continuity of the solution <= C x the modulus of continuity of the boundary data?